# Some div are moving up, in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, height

In Our frame work, we have this kind of HTML Structure.

```
<body>
  <div id = header>
  <div id = menu>
  <div id = keildo>
    <iframe src=...>
    </iframe>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here, inside we are rendering pages on click of some button inside `iframe`, we are hiding this `iframe` and showing different `iframe` with some content. But on click of that button, when we are showing diff `iframe`, `div`(kailedo is moving up) hence div header and menu are not visible. But if through Firebug if m change height or over flow of kaildo `div`, then all div's are visible.

This is working fine in all other browsers.

Comment: can u paste some snippet css code for #keildo

Comment: html{
 margin:1px;
 padding:0px;
 height:100%;
 overflow:hidden; 
}
#header
{
 width:100%;
}

#menubar
{
 height:26px; 
 width:100%; 
}


#kaledo
{
 margin-top:1px;
 width: 100%;
 float:right;
 height:100%; 
 margin-bottom:1px;
}